# Clip Path coordinates programmatically

Tags: php, jakarta-ee, geometry

I've some paths and I would like to clip these paths to a specific region (green) resulting in the remaining paths (red):

[image]

What is the best way/approach to do this commonly with manually cutting the paths?

Comment: This is basic 2D graphics clipping. You can find the solution elsewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose any suitable [line-clipping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-clipping).

I've used Liang–Barsky one.
(Wiki page is so-so, try to find some better description)